# Problems with Unicode like string

Tags: python, ios, django, unicode

I write API for iOS client using django framework and have problem with Unicode like string. Client sends me string, which contains this: `\U0424\U0444\U0444\U042d`.

I can't figure out how to parse it? What encoding it is? It is russian literals.

Originally I get this:

`{\n    value = \\\"\\U0424\\U0444\\U0444\\U042d\\\";\n    data1 = \"{\\n  x = \\\"75.5\\\";\\n    y = \\\"206.75\\\";\\n}\";\n    data2 = 12;\n    data4 = 1395911055;\n data5 = \\\"value\\\";\n}"`

Comment: That is *almost* valid JSON. Are you sure it is not something like `"\u0424\u0444\u0444\u042d"` instead? E.g. with double quotes and **lowercase** `\u` escapes, because *then* it means `ФффЭ`.

Comment: I'm sure that I get not in lowercase.

Comment: What wonderfully weird format then, because with just 4 digits that's now not valid JSON. Can you give us a more complete sample of the data, not just these 4 characters?

Comment: I've just updated question with original string.

Comment: Oh my, that's a lovely mess. Some quotes are escaped, others are not. That's indeed not JSON.

Comment: I retrieve all values with regex, it is fine. Main problem with strings which are not in ascii.

Comment: At which point you convert `\U([a-fA-F0-9]{4})` to `\u<four hex digits` and decode those with the `unicode_escape` codec.

Comment: I retrive \U0424\U044\\04444\\U042d using more dumb way.I just use 
r"^[\s\S]+value\s*\=\s*[\\\"]*(?P<value>.*[^;\\\"])[\\\"]*;$" and after I don't use unicode_escape codec at any point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters unicode_escape just gives the same as originally posted with screened backslashes.

Comment: You'd *decode*, and you need to use lowercase `\u` for it to work.

Comment: Why unicode_escape codec I need here, why not utf?

Comment: Because this is not a UTF encoding. It's an escape sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have JSON data, you have a proprietary Apple format, it appears.

If you are already parsing the data successfully except for the string data containing these references, I'd not parse this as JSON, but as Python strings with unicode escapes. You'll have to massage the text a little to be compatible:

```
import re

escaped = re.sub(r'\\U([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})', r'\\u\1', inputstring)
result = escaped.decode('unicode_escape')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputstring = '\U0424\U0444\U0444\U042d'
>>> escaped = re.sub(r'\\U([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})', r'\\u\1', inputstring)
>>> escaped
'\\u0424\\u0444\\u0444\\u042d'
>>> escaped.decode('unicode_escape')
u'\u0424\u0444\u0444\u042d'
>>> print escaped.decode('unicode_escape')
ФффЭ
```

Answer (score 2):

The data you received is in (almost) JSON format. Use `json.loads` to parse such things:

```
>>> json.loads('"\u0424\u0444\u0444\u042d"')  # Valid JSON.
'ФффЭ'
```

Comment: Not without first *lowercasing* the `U`s to `u`, provided there are quotes around the string too.

Comment: You still need quotes first. Most likely the *original data* contains lowercase `u`; don't replace them automatically like that because you'll almost certainly replace legitimate `U` characters.

Comment: No, I meant the quotes are part of the *string data*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was wondering what you meant, thank you. :)

Comment: @AlexThornton I tried your solution, but got ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded. So, indeed it's not JSON originally.